# Blazor Server | Ограничение создание "контента" на время

Tags: .net, веб-программирование, asp, blazor

Дайте направление куда копать.Есть сайт на котором любой пользователь(авторизированный) может добавить
"Контент",например,добавление своей "статьи".
Как мне ограничить, чтобы пользователь мог за сутки добавлять N статьей.Хотелось бы и не только за сутки,но и раз в N-часов узнать,вдруг решение отличаться будет.

Вопрос общий,что в него входит "Что хранить бд для записи времени","Как лучше проверять прошедшее время"
Спасибо.

Comment: Почему бы не хранить DateTime со всеми вытекающими?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне подсказали изучать

> Rate Limiting